# What is the quickest way to end a transaction when no changes have been made?

Tags: transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL server 2008 R2, and the function OpenSqlFilestream to obtain a file handle to open a file with read only access.  I need this to be as quick as possible.  OpenSqlFilestream requires being called within a transaction context, even though I won't be committing any changes to the file.  Once I have done with the file I need to get rid of the transaction.  What would be quicker, a commit or a rollback and why?  Or is there some way to simple discard the transaction?  I will not be modifying any rows or the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a discussion here already: [Should I commit or rollback a read transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309834/should-i-commit-or-rollback-a-read-transaction)