# After a read-only database transaction is it better to commit or rollback?

Tags: database, transactions

If you have a database transaction that should be read only, do you commit or rollback?  Is there any reason to do one or the other?  Does one of the approachs improve database performance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I commit or rollback a read transaction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309834/should-i-commit-or-rollback-a-read-transaction)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I commit or rollback a read transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309834/should-i-commit-or-rollback-a-read-transaction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some RDMS (at least Oracle ) have READ ONLY isolation level. Otherwise, I prefer `ROLLBACK` since it doesn't create an entry in transaction log (a bit better from performance point of view).

**Update**
Some explanations.
Most RDMS log all committed transactions and changes associated with transaction. Even if no changes are made, server logs a transaction. I don't see any points in wasting server resources by storing useless data.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Downpour046
I do the following for read only operations. Works like a charm, no issues.

```
Session session;
    synchronized (this) {
        session = currentSession();
        Query rowResult = session.createSQLQuery(rowQuery).addEntity(table.getClass());
        tableRow = rowResult.list().toArray();
    }
public Session currentSession() {
    Session s = (Session) session.get();
    // Open a new Session, if this thread has none yet
    if (s == null || !s.isOpen()) {
        s = sessionFactory.openSession();
        // Store it in the ThreadLocal variable
        session.set(s);
    }
    return s;
}
```