# NHibernate - Only select, should I commit or rollback?

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, transactions

When doing a Select in nhibernate I suppose a Rollback is faster than a Commit since neither NHibernate nor Oracle has to do any checks for if anything is updated.

But all examples I have found does a Commit after Selecting.
While if I use an implicit transaction the framework does a Rollback.

My question is about *speed and resource use*, not about architecture or coding stye.

( Now the ones who write nhibernate know way more about the innards of nhibernate than I do and they have chosen to make a Rollback on an implicit transaction with only Select. This might be to totally different reasons than I have (not committing must lead to a rollback being a possible reason). )

( There is also an architectural/psychological argument around what should happen in a possible future edit where someone decides to call an Update in the same code. Should the dev be surprised by a Rollback or should a misplaced Update surprise the users with a Commit? This discussion is *not* part of the main question. )

```
using (var session = Helper.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        var ret = session.Query<Person>().Where(x => x.Id == id).Single();
        tran.Rollback();  // <----- or commit?
        return ret;
    }
}
```

or should I call

```
tran.Commit();
```

?

Comment: Why do you need to use a transaction if you are only performing a single select?

Comment: Someone much more knowledgeable than me [suggests](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof/learn/alert/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions) it. Resistance is futile - there will be a transaction.

Answer (score 3):

First off, as you stated in your comment, you should *always* wrap code using NHibernate in a transaction.

I'm not sure about performance implications of rolling back vs committing, but I've found the idea of a read-only transaction (i.e., a transaction that always gets rolled back at the end of use) to be useful for two main reasons:

1. Your code clearly indicates that work done inside of the read only transaction will not write anything down to the database, and
2. You protect yourself from [ghost updates](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/nhibernate-pitfalls-ghosts) caused by bad NHibernate mappings.

It does makes sense intuitively that rolling back a transaction would  be a bit faster, but I can't find any (NHibernate) documentation to back that up.

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead with committing the transaction, since you started it and there is no error. Even if you use it for select.

Have a look at this too : [Should I commit or rollback a read transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309834/should-i-commit-or-rollback-a-read-transaction)

Comment: The post answers mainly results in a "If you haven't changed anything, then you can use either a COMMIT or a ROLLBACK. Either one will release any read locks you have acquired and since you haven't made any other changes, they will be equivalent.". Yes they are from a functional perspective from the client. But performance wise they might not be.

Comment: Yes... but in practice if some other developer alter the code and add an update operation in the middle of select statements, there is a potential of update is not working if someone choose to use rollback. Using commit operations in some places and using rollback other places will cause consistency issues in software as I believe.

Comment: On the other hand, if a later developer adds an Update in something that is designed to be a Select it might be a good choice to have this update not work. The developer has a good chance of finding out that his/her code does not work. While catching that other code, relying on this Select, fails due to a newly added Update might be harder. A matter of opinion/design really, to decide who owns the bugs and the responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge into the ins and outs of DB stuff needs work but the way i thought transactions occured were more like 1 way than 2 way.

Meaning Update, Insert, Delete i am "Setting" the data, this is a transaction that may need a rollback etc.

Selecting data im "Getting" existing data, im not changing the data or effecting its values there for there is no need for a transaction to occur.

As far as i can tell when you refer to "Commit", i cant see that occuring on a select, as i said it appears there isnt a transaction taking place as im simply getting data, not changing its values.

Maybe someone with some concrete facts could advice better.